# How to draw a polyline with strokeweight larger than 32px

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I'm trying to draw a thick polyline using Google maps API V3, but it turns out that the maximum strokeweight allowed is 32px. Is there any way to work around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you require a Polyline that exceeds 32 pixels in width, the correct approach is to use Polygons instead of Polylines. Using Polygons and setting the strokeColor to be the same colour as the fillColor, and with the same opacity on stroke and fill, will achieve what you want.

```
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  const lineCoords = [
    { lat: -37.813798, lng: 144.917028 },
    { lat: -37.813837, lng: 144.917033 },
    { lat: -37.813886, lng: 144.919991 },
    { lat: -37.813831, lng: 144.919967 },
    { lat: -37.813798, lng: 144.917028 }
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  const myPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: lineCoords,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 1,
  });

  myPolygon.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way you could additionally style google maps polylines is presented inside the google maps documentation. There is no other way in which you could extend the styling.

You could try with pure CSS, but it wouldn't reflect to the actual google map.

So yes, this is about it:

```
  var path = new google.maps.Polyline(
    {
              path: route,
              strokeColor: "#FF0000",
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 32
        });
```

It's really odd that the docs do not mention the limit of the strokeweight. They only state the following strokeWeight

> strokeWeight   Type:  number The stroke width in pixels.